# How to make auto-indentation work correctly after macros ending with semicolons

Tags: indentation

I'm using `cindent` with C++ sources, and when I put some macro, which already ends with a semicolon, like Qt's `Q_OBJECT`, `cindent` doesn't understand it and makes an extra indentation on the next line.

For emacs there [seems to be an option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19995905/673852) to use/edit `c-macro-names-with-semicolon` variable, which apparently would make the indenter understand these particular macros correctly.

Is there any similar option in Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:help 'cindent'` mentions `:help C-indenting`, which contains the following:

```
Note that 'cindent' indenting does not work for every code scenario.  Vim
is not a C compiler: it does not recognize all syntax.  One requirement is
that toplevel functions have a '{' in the first column.  Otherwise they are
easily confused with declarations.

These four options control C program indenting:
'cindent'       Enables Vim to perform C program indenting automatically.
'cinkeys'       Specifies which keys trigger reindenting in insert mode.
'cinoptions'    Sets your preferred indent style.
'cinwords'      Defines keywords that start an extra indent in the next line.
```

In order to achieve the what you described it would be necessary to know how the macro would expanded; but this would require that Vim behaving as a *compiler*, which, as noticed above, it does not.

If there would be an option equivalent to `c-macro-names-with-semicolon` it would be part of the `'cinoptions'`. But if you check `:help cinoptions-values` you will notice that despite it is possible to make a number of customizations, there is nothing similar to what you are looking for.

But you could try using `'indentexpr'` along`'cindent'`. Also from `:help C-indenting`

```
There are in fact four main methods available for indentation, each one
overrides the previous if it is enabled, or non-empty for 'indentexpr':
'autoindent'    uses the indent from the previous line.
'smartindent'   is like 'autoindent' but also recognizes some C syntax to
        increase/reduce the indent where appropriate.
'cindent'   Works more cleverly than the other two and is configurable to
        different indenting styles.
'indentexpr'    The most flexible of all: Evaluates an expression to compute
        the indent of a line.  When non-empty this method overrides
        the other ones.  See |indent-expression|.
```

By using `'indentexpr'` you could use a custom function to analyze the contents of the macro (possibly using ctags) and them return the correct amount of indentation.

If you are concerned with a few known macros you could try using the "[genindent.vim plugin: Generic function for indentexpr](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=678)" to make `'cindent'` ignore lines referencing those macros.